# Make an empty DIV height and width of its container

Tags: css, html, background-color

My HTML currently contains a background image that stretches with the viewport. Within that, I plan to place a `div` that stretches to the height and width of the viewport and has black background colour at 50% opacity.

I've set the `div` to be 100% width and height. The `div` is not stretching and I can't figure out why!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en"> 
    <head>
        <title>Tester</title>   
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/> 
        <style type="text/css"> 
            html { 
                background: url(http://cjpstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/cityrock1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;
            }

            #background-color   {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: #000000;
            }       
        </style>
    </head> 
    <body>  
        <div id="background-color"> 
        </div>  
    </body>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/zdwhK/

Comment: The end result above is meant to be that the user sees an entirely black viewport. This is because the `div` fills the entire viewport and has a `background-color` value of `#000000`.

Answer (score 4):

For an alternative to `width` and `height` you could use, instead, `position`:

```
#background-color {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

This will, or may, allow a user to scroll the page which will move the `#background-color` element, to avoid the possibility of the user moving the image, use `position: fixed` instead.

If the `#background-color` element has an ancestor element with a `position` other than `static` this element will be positioned relative to that ancestor, rather than the page/document (for `position: absolute`) or the viewport (for `position: fixed`).

Though if this is an attempt at preventing user-interaction with the content of your site it is, of course, doomed to failure.

---

**Edited** in response to comment from OP, below:

> Can you explain why? I don't understand how/were the `div` is getting instructions to fill the window. I thought I thoroughly understood `position` though... I guess not. Anyway, an explanation would be really helpful.

Sure, it's not much of an explanation though, this simply works by positioning the element with either `absolute` or `fixed`, and then positioning its axes against the sides of the viewport, `0px` from the `top`, `0px` from the `left` side, `0px` from the `right` side and `0px` from the `bottom`.

Comment: Hah! This is not an attempt at preventing user-interaction within the content of my site, no. I'm just building the base-layer for a much larger site and seem to be having problems with something I thought would be really basic.

Comment: Sidenote, rgba has poor support among IE versions

Comment: @david, your solution works, thank you. Can you explain why? I don't understand how/were the `div` is getting instructions to fill the window. I thought I thoroughly understood `position` though... I guess not. Anyway, an explanation would be really helpful.

Comment: @david, thank you for the explanation, really helpful. However! I've found a problem as I continue development. My content width is 960px. When I make the viewport smaller than that width, the `#background-color` `div` behaves as expected, until I scroll to the right, at which point I see that the `div` is only covering the width of the viewport in its initial position. I hope that's a good enough explanation!

Answer (score 2):

set a width and (min-)height of 100% on both the html and body tag. Also note the @black instead of black.

And if you want a full page block. Setting the element as fixed with the 100% width and height you have now is probably better(as mentioned in other comments)

Fixed works better because it will match the element to the window element. Absolute will match the element to the nearest ancestor with either relative, absolute or fixed positioning. Fixed is supported since IE7.

Comment: Sorry, caught the @black, that didn't relate to the issue but I changed it above for clarity. Will try what you suggest now.

Answer (score 1):

The background will not show because there is no content in that div. If you want the div to cover the page without there being any content this seemed to work for me

```
#background-color   {
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            width:100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: @black;
            }
```

Hopefully this will work for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need the position as absolute in this case, I just edit your code for you to do exactly what you want:

```css
html {
  background: url(http://chrisjepson.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/PrideBus2017_CJP2043-web-700x485.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#background-color {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tester</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="background-color"></div>
</body>

</html>
```